# How to hide a button or a section in TWIG if not logged in OpenCart 3.x?

Tags: opencart-3

I need to hide a button and section in section in cart page of OpenCart 3.x. There is no TWIG code found for if customer logged in. Can anyone please give me a section to do it?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I can do it by declaring the logged in value into a variable like below.

In controller:

```
$data['loggedin'] = $this->customer->isLogged();
```

In View:

```
{% if loggedin %}
<sections> or Whatever
{% endif %}
```